# How to get approximate file path?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list file path as follow:

```
C:\Data\Default.aspx
C:\Data\Global.asax
C:\Data\Web.config
C:\Data\bin\PerlsComWebProject1.dll
C:\Data\bin\PerlsComWebProject1.pdb
```

I have a method to get file from folder path, however I want to print result as below:

```
Data\Default
Data\Global
Data\Web.config
Data\bin\PerlsComWebProject1
Data\bin\PerlsComWebProject1
```

Call: `GetFilePathWithOutExtention(@"C:\\Data");`

My code is only return file without an extension.

```
void GetFilePathWithOutExtention(string path)
{
    string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach(var path in paths)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));
    }
}
```

**Update:** Thanks for your comments. "C:\Data\" is only a sample, sorry so make you confused. Actual, I have a any folder, I want to search this folder, get approximate path: this folder...\filename with out extention.

Ex: I have a path as follow: D:\EHO\Phase1\Data\Document\text.txt,....when I call method: GetFilePathWithOutExtention("D:\EHO\Phase1"), I want to output: Phase1\Data\Document\text, or GetFilePathWithOutExtention("D:\EHO\Phase1\Data"), output: Data\Document\text.

Thanks.

Comment: Just remove `C:` part after your `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` method?

Comment: what is your logic? i cannot find a valid logic for the output you mentioned `Data\Web.config`

Comment: because `path` is a `string` you can just write `path.Substring(2)`

Comment: The better way would be to remove the parent path of the `path` variable of his method

Comment: @SonerGönül: Remove C: is not a good solution, I have a any path, ex: D:\EHO\Phase1\Data\Document\text.txt

Comment: @bansi: Hi bansi, I have a struct folder contain data file. I must search in directory, get approximate file and fill to xml. If you want to detail, I will inbox. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic answer, valid for all folders inside the machine drives, not only 1st level:

```
void GetFilePathWithOutExtention(string path)
{
    // Get the name of the folder containing your path (for further remove in the items folder)
    string parentFolderName = Directory.GetParent(path).FullName;

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach(string fileItemPath in filePaths)
    {
        // Get the current folder without the initial folder path
        string currentItemPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileItemPath).Remove(0, parentFolderName.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(currentItemPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileItemPath)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `Uri.MakeRelativeUri`

So you could do something like this:

```
  var folder = new Uri(@"C:\Data");
  var paths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder.LocalPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
  foreach (var uri in paths.Select(p => new Uri(p)))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(folder.MakeRelativeUri(uri).ToString());
  }
```

This prints

```
Data/Default.aspx
Data/Global.asax
Data/Web.config
Data/bin/PerlsComWebProject1.dll
Data/bin/PerlsComWebProject1.pdb
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just Show from the 4th char

```
void GetFilePathWithOutExtention(string path)
{
    string[] filesName = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach(var fileName in filesName)
     {
         string pathToWrite = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
         if(pathToWrite != null && pathToWrite.length >3 )
           Console.WriteLine(pathToWrite.Substring(3,pathToWrite.length);
     }
}
```

Comment: What is his path is more than 2 characters and/or more than 1 folder ? (and also you mispelled length)

Comment: @NicolasR this code will write from the 4th char to the end of string, then all folder, substring only to delete "c:\"

Comment: I know. but you are restricted in the case the user look in a folder like `C:\myFolder`. A more generic method would be better, using the path in the variable

Comment: Nicolas which path are you refering to? Akrem, I think this, and the OPs code, won't compile since you are reassigning the `path` variable (foreach and method parameter)

Comment: Sayse: see my answer: I think it would be a better approach to do a method which is also valid if called with `C:\Folder1\MyRequestFolder` parameter for example. If I'm right, the OP says he want to get all the files relative to the current folder, `Data` in his sample, but what if is sample was `C:\Folder1\Data`? We can't just remove the 3 first characters, don't we?

But I agree with you, in his basic sample, this answer should work